# Customize borders of Kendo UI grid in angular 5 application

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular5

I have an angular 5 application with the library Kendo UI.
In this application I have a Kendo UI Grid and I want to customize it with some borders.
This is my grid:

[image: My Grid]

I have blue border-left when the row are on hover or when they are expanded.
But in want to have a little space between the two blue lines of two different row when the two are expanded.

So, in fact, I want to put the grey border on the bottom over the blue border on left or add a little white space a the bottom or top of the blue border.

This is the code of my grid :

```
<kendo-grid
      id="myGrid"
      #grid
      [kendoGridBinding]="listOfSolution"
      [resizable]="false"
      [pageSize]="10"
      [pageable]="true"
      [sortable]="true"
      [sort]="sortByNbTransit"
      [filterable]="false"
      [groupable]="false"
      [reorderable]="false"
      [selectable]="false"
      [scrollable]="'none'"
      [rowClass]="rowCallback()"
      (detailCollapse)="onCollapse($event)"
       (detailExpand)="onExpand($event)"
      (sortChange)="onSort($event)"
      style="border: none;">
      <kendo-grid-column [width]="90" field="serviceName" title="SERVICE" [style]="{'min-width':'90px','margin-left':'18px !important'}" [sortable]="false">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              <span>{{ dataItem.routingDetails[0].service.name}}</span>
         </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column width="110px" field="vesselName" title="VESSEL" [style]="{'min-width':'110px'}" [sortable]="false"></kendo-grid-column>
      <ng-template [kendoGridDetailTemplateShowIf]="displayOrHideDetails" kendoGridDetailTemplate let-dataItem class="expandDetails">
          <div style="width: 100%; display: table;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div *ngFor="let data of dataItem.routingDetails" style="display: table-row">
                 <div class="detailsCell" style="min-width: 90px">
                      <span class="detailText">{{ data.service.name }}</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="detailsCell" style="min-width: 110px;">
                      <span class="detailText">{{ data.vessel.name }}</span>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
      </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

Do you know how I could do that ?